# json type in Cassandra data model?

Tags: cql3, cassandra-2.0, cqlengine

I am wondering if I could have `json` data type in the `column family`:

My table will have a unique `row key`, and column name of "tweets_json" and column value of json content.

How would I create such a table in `CQL/cassandra` or using `python Driver` or `CQLengine`?

```
tweet_json = json.encode({
                "tweet_id" : tweet_id,
                "body" : tweet_body,
                "user_name" : this_user,
                "timestamp" : timestamp
            })
```

Basicall

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just have a text column? If you're not looking to filter on the json, then that should be fine. If you are, then you'll need to store it as proper columns, rather than as json.

Comment: I would like to filter. Does cassandra not support json?

Comment: No. 
In cassandra, you store data with a schema in rows with columns. You can filter on certain columns depending on how you structure your data. As such, an important part is doing some data modelling based on your query patterns to get the best performance / scalability / cluster utilisation.

Comment: In your case, you could have a table like this:

create table tweets( user_name text, tweet_id text, body text, timestamp timestamp, primary key(user_name, timestamp));

But this would again depend on how you wish to query the info.

Comment: You can use maps, which collection columns. You can index them in cassandra 2.1. Have a look at http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cql-in-2-1 .

Comment: There are further plans in 3.0 to support JSON that maps onto C* strict schema.